# Sidebar not staying collapsed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using the [AdminLTE theme](https://almsaeedstudio.com/preview) for the front end of my website.

It has a side menu that is popped out by default, that can be collapsed.

The theme doesn't come with any way to remember this from page to page, and so I am using local storage in HTML5 to remember their choice and then implement this on the page.

The issue with this is that it has to wait for the page to load, and the menu is maximised by default and then my script to check the storage loads, checks whether the menu should be collapsed and then closes the menu - along with the animation to do this.

So every time the page changes, or reloads the user sees the menu collapse.

You can see what I mean through the link below - close the menu and then when you refresh the page it pops out again:

https://almsaeedstudio.com/preview

And this is the script I am using to keep it closed:

```
 //using local storage to remember if sidebar toggled
 $(document).ready(function(){
   if (Boolean(localStorage.getItem("sidebar-toggle-collapsed", "1"))) { //check if sidebar-toggle-collapsed is set to 1 in local storage
     $("body").removeClass('sidebar-collapse'); //make sidebar large
   }
   if (Boolean(localStorage.getItem("sidebar-toggle-collapsed", ""))) { //check if sidebar-toggle-collapsed is set to nothing in local storage
     $("body").addClass('sidebar-collapse'); //make sidebar small (collapsed)
   }
   $('.sidebar-toggle').click(function() {
       if (Boolean(localStorage.getItem("sidebar-toggle-collapsed"))) {
         localStorage.setItem("sidebar-toggle-collapsed", "");
       } else {
         localStorage.setItem("sidebar-toggle-collapsed", "1");
       }
     });
 })
```

;

**How can I make it stay collapsed without people seeing it happen on every page load?** I can likely do this backend by storing their choice in a database, but it seems silly to have to do this, which is why I want to see if there is any way to do this front end first.

Comment: So its like if they close the `menu` it should be closed on page refresh and if they keep it open it should be kept open on page reload right?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao correct. Using local storage, as above, it remembers their choice and works - but it always starts maximised and then closes. resulting in the user seeing the sidebar close every time they go to a new page.

Comment: Try removing it from `document.ready` and place it outside.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao it doesn't work - still happens.

Comment: In fact you cannot control it from happening as it waits for all the document element to get loaded completely. Its better if you keep preference on server side and design the view accordingly..

Comment: Or else initially do not open it and then based on the `locaStorage` you can open it up.. Will that be good enough?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao that would then cause the opposite to happen and the sidebar would pop out for everyone else.